# Prefilled values in edit modal issue

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4RPH.png)

I am making the crud operation with AJAX jQuery request. I want to made the edit and update crud with AJAX request. I have made it with the modal. but when I click my edit modal it opens but it does not goto to my success function. Plus it did not `console.log` my `res.data.id` `res.data.first_name` values. now I don't know what to do.  And it did not show me any prefilled values.

HTML

```
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($employee as $row) : ?>
            <!-- <tr id="</?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> -->
            <!-- <td><//?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> -->
            <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->first_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->last_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->phone ?></td>
            <td><?php echo$row->email ?></td>
            <td>
                <a data-id="<?php echo $row->id  ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"
                   class="btn btn-success btn-sm btnEdit">Edit</a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a data-id="<?php echo $row->id ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">Confirm Delete</button>
            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="hdnemployeeId" id="employeeId"/>
                <!-- ?php echo base_url('employee/update'); -->
                <form id="updateEmployee" name="updateEmployee" action="<?php echo site_url('employee/update');?>"  method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="first_name" name="txtfirstname" placeholder="First Name">
                        <small><?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="last_name" name="txtlastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <small><?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" name="txtphone" placeholder="Phone">
                        <small><?php echo form_error('phone'); ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="txtemail" placeholder="Email">
                        <small><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

AJAX jQuery

```
<script>
    // databale version 1.11.5 with jquery 3.5.1
    $(document).ready(function() {
        new DataTable('#employeeTable');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.btnEdit', function() {
        var employee_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        //alert(id);
        //console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("employee/edit/") ?>' + employee_id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                //console.log(res);
                alert(res);
                //   console.log(res.data.id);
                // console.log(res.data.first_name);
                // console.log(res.data.last_name);
                // console.log(res.data.phone);
                // console.log(res.data.email);
                $('#editModal').modal('show');
                $('#employeeId').val(res.data.id);
                $('#first_name').val(res.data.first_name);
                $('#last_name').val(res.data.last_name);
                $('#phone').val(res.data.phone);
                $('#email').val(res.data.email);
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more clues about how to post a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Firstly, you need to share some debugging details, start with your browser console to check if does there any errors.

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.btnEdit', function()` you are listening to the `click` event on the `btnEdit` class, while your code does not share any element with this class!

Comment: ok i will do it. second of all my btnEdit class is on my edit button
plus i can't see any      // console.log(res.data.first_name);
on my console screen @hassan

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Is `employee_id` correctly set - you hvae commented out `console.log(id)` but there is no `id`, what about `employee_id`?  Is your HTML correctly rendered?  The PHP does not help us here, we don't have your DB - what does the generated source look like?  Check your browser's devtools network tab - does the AJAX request happen?  Is the URL with `employee_id` correct? What does the back end respond with? BTW you are missing an opening `<tr>`.